# Creating a new remote repository from EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I want to share an Eclipse project over git (EGit).

I successfully created a local repository for the project. I understand, that to add a remote repository, it must already exist on a remote machine. I succeeded adding an existing remote bare repository.

Is there a way to automatically create a remote repository with EGit if it does not exist yet? In the end of the day, Eclipse uses the same SSH connection to connect to a remote server as I use to manually create a remote repository.

Or am I missing something?

I am using a private NAS as a remote server and have full control over it.

Thanks 
Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to automatically create a remote repository with EGit if it does not exist yet?

Not that I know of. EGit will use ssh or https in order to connect to the remote server and pass the git command there.

But that won't create the repo on said server anymore than it would if you were to git push to a different folder within your own computer (local computer which you have full control over it as well).
You would get a:

```
 fatal: 'path\to\repo' does not appear to be a git repository
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Comment: I was wondering if EGit could also send "git init" for a non-existing repository. But logically it should also create directories, set access rights, etc. I understand, that that would normally be impossible for a git user due to his limited rights.