# Create Remote Repository from egit

Tags: eclipse, git, github, egit

I have a local git repository which I want to share it in a remote git repository (say github.com). Is there any way to create the remote repository using eGit (if the remote repository is not existing already)?

I have seen this link:
[Creating a new remote repository from EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961791/creating-a-new-remote-repository-from-egit)

That question is 5 years old, just wondering if there is any update on that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would have to confirm my 2014 answer.

[EGit](https://www.eclipse.org/egit/) alone would not create a remote repository.

Only a `curl` call to the remote Git hosting repository service (like the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/)) would be able to do so ([Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56099606/6309)).
And that call would not be the same as the one you would do to create a new repository on BitBucket or GitLab.

You would at least need [`eclipse/egit-github`](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github)

> EGit Github Connector is an Eclipse plugin for working with Git repositories hosted on Github. It is based on the JGit library, which is a Git implementation in pure Java and integrates with EGit which is the Eclipse Git Team Provider.

---

Note: it is true [GitLab allows to create a new repo on first push](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/gitlab-basics/create-project.html#push-to-create-a-new-project).
But that is a feature specific to GitLab, and not generally available on other services.